# Configurar multiples <virtualhost> con un mismo Certificado SSL - Apache

Tags: apache, ssl, virtualhost

Estaba configurando un par de dominios que compartieran un mismo certificado SSL, que el contenido se encontrará en distintas carpetas y evidentemente que todo se encontrara en el mismo servidor.

Mis dominios son:

> example.com       (Para el Sitio Web)
>
> api.example.com   (Para el Web Service)

Consegui el Certificado SSL con *Let's Encrypt* <s>(gratuito)</s>.

El certificado fue generado para ambos dominios, por lo tanto se podia situar en un mismo directorio.

> /etc/apache2/ssl/example.com/

Posteriormente realicé las configuraciones respectivas en el directorio de sitios de Apache.

> /etc/apache2/sites-available/

Asi tambien, realice la activacion de los sitios:

> a2ensite example.com
>
> a2ensite api.example.com

La estructura del sitio web es:

```
-> /var/www/
       -> website/
       -> api/
```

### Estas son las configuraciones:

#### /etc/apache2/sites-available/example.com

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName  example.com
    DocumentRoot    /var/www/website/

    LogLevel debug
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/example.com/error.log

        <Directory "/var/www/website/">
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>

    ServerName  example.com
    DocumentRoot    /var/www/website/

    LogLevel debug
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/example.com/error_ssl.log

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateKeyFile   /etc/apache2/ssl/example.com/privkey.pem
    SSLCertificateFile      /etc/apache2/ssl/example.com/cert.pem
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/example.com/chain.pem

        <Directory "/var/www/website/">
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

#### /etc/apache2/sites-available/api.example.com

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName  api.example.com
    DocumentRoot    /var/www/api/

    #RewriteEngine On
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}$1 [R=301,L]

        <Directory "/var/www/api/">
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>

    ServerName  api.example.com
    DocumentRoot    /var/www/api/

    LogLevel warn
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateKeyFile   /etc/apache2/ssl/example.com/privkey.pem
    SSLCertificateFile      /etc/apache2/ssl/example.com/cert.pem
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/example.com/chain.pem

        <Directory "/var/www/api/">
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

**El inconveniente es:**

#### ***Cuando accedo el sitio `example.com` en el navegador se abre el contenido que tiene `api.example.com`.***

**Esto da el origen a mi pregunta:**

### *¿Como podemos configurar varios sitios usando el mismo Certificado SSL?*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Les comparto mi solución.

Despues de buscar un poco acerca de este requerimiento encontre este parametro de Apache.

> SSLStrictSNIVHostCheck

La cual nos da a conocer un termino respecto al Apache.

### SNI

### Server Name Indication

De acuerdo a una referencia de Internet, cito:

> SNI permite que el cliente, antes de cifrar la conexión, envié al servidor el nombre del dominio al que desea acceder. [[1]](https://chicheblog.wordpress.com/2013/02/10/servir-multiples-virtualhosts-ssl-con-una-unica-ip-en-ubuntu/)

Esto quiere decir que debemos habilitar `SNI` en nuestro servidor para poder atender multiples subdominios usando el mismo Certificado SSL.

#### Como lo hacemos?

Lo primero que se hace es modificar el siguiente fichero:

> /etc/apache2/httpd.conf

Y en el agregamos lo siguiente:

> SSLStrictSNIVHostCheck on

Posteriormente, se edita el fichero:

> /etc/apache2/ports.conf

Y en el agregamos la siguiente instruccion:

```
NameVirtualHost *:443

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    # If you add NameVirtualHost *:443 here, you will also have to change
    # the VirtualHost statement in /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl
    # to <VirtualHost *:443>
    # Server Name Indication for SSL named virtual hosts is currently not
    # supported by MSIE on Windows XP.
    Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

La instruccion `NameVirtualHost *:443` es mas necesaria de agregar, ya que lo que se encuentra debajo de esta, suele estar por defecto en la configuracion de `ports.conf`.

Finalmente, guardamos y reinciamos el Apache.

> /etc/init.d/apache2 restart

Despues de esto, los subdominios permiten su utilizacion de manera independiente y utilizando el mismo Certificado SSL.

### Actualizacion

La directiva `ServerName` indica uno de los nombres de servidor que puede ser usado en el `virtualhost`, mas podemos usar otra directiva, que nos puede servir si son multiples dominios que usen el mismo contenido.

> ServerAlias

Quedando nuestra configuracion asi.

```
ServerName    example.com
ServerAlias   www.example.com
ServerAlias   sitio.example.com
```

Permitiendo que la misma configuracion para `example.com` pueda ser usada por otros sitios.

Comment: buen descubrimiento

Comment: Let's Encrypt te permite crear un certificado para un dominio (y sus sub-dominios que es lo que realmente planteas en tu post) por lo que puedes usar dicho certificado en ambos servidores virtuales sin problemas, no es necesario hacer nada de lo que panteas en tu post.